# For analyzing time series data, how should I do linear regression on trend and seasonality in Python?

Tags: python, r

I apologize if there is any formatting issue in my first post.

For example, I have the linear model in R using function tslm to do regression model:

```
    x <- tslm(dataframe ~ trend + a + b + c, dataframe_without_time)
```

for which a, b and c are three independent variables; dataframe is the original data with columns of date and three independent variables; dataframe_without_time is the data with only three independent variables.

By executing this tslm function, I get x as a linear regression on trend, a, b and c. This tslm function can also handle regression on seasonality and interaction terms.

Now I wish to know how should I get the same result using Python. I have tried using seasonal_decompose function and it will get trend and seasonality for a, b, and c, but then I do not know what to do.

I sincerely appreciate if anyone could give me a hint how to proceed, or is there any equivalent function in python as tslm function in R?

Comment: Could You please add some source code which shows:
1. How You create your data Frame, including some example data.
2. where the function `seasonal_decompose` comes from